# How to add listview items from one activity to listview in another activity in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a Mainactivity which contain listview and also i have another activity called "WhiteList" which is also containing listview, what i want to add listview items from MainActivity to Listview items of another activity. Please help me do that

code of adapter:-

```
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<AppList> listStorage;
    private Context mContext;
    int newarr_pos=0;
    public AppAdapter(Context context, List<AppList> customizedListView) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        listStorage = customizedListView;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listStorage.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder listViewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list, parent, false);

            listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
            listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
            listViewHolder.switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
            convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
        } else {
            listViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
        listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());
        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setTag(position);

        listViewHolder.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext,R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle).setTitle("Warning").setMessage("You want to whiteList this application?").setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //here i am adding items to another arraylist
                            List<WhiteListModel> res = new ArrayList<WhiteListModel>();
                            String name = listStorage.get(position).getName();
                            Drawable icon = listStorage.get(position).getIcon();
                            String packageName = listStorage.get(position).getPackName();
                            res.add(new WhiteListModel(name,icon,packageName));


                            listStorage.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();


                            listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            listViewHolder.switchCompat.setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }).show();

                }


            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        SwitchCompat switchCompat;
        TextView textInListView;
        ImageView imageInListView;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem in that set the same adaptor for both the listview'

Comment: Do you want to show the checked items in your second activity?

Comment: How to i set same Adapter......

Comment: yes i want to show checked items in my second activity in android

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want same list in both activities, while launching another activity you can pass your list to that activity like below:

```
intent.putExtra("LIST", myList);
```

Then retrieve list:

```
ArrayList<TypeOfList> myList = (ArrayList<TypeOfList>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("LIST");
```

Finally set the list to your listview:

```
yourAdapter.setList(myList);
listView.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```